# In Gitlab Pipeline how to add another condition in the same rule using reference

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

In gitlab pipeline I have a job with rule using "reference". How do I add another condition in the same rule using

```
.rules:default:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "main" && $VERSION_NUMBER != "current"

myjob:
  stage: myjob
  script:
    - echo "I am executing myjob"
  rules:    
    - $Environment == "sbx" && !reference [".rules:default", rules]
```

this show this as error `This GitLab CI configuration is invalid: jobs:myjob rules should be an array containing hashes and arrays of hashes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do string interpolations with `!reference` -- there are no interpolation primitives in the YAML spec, either.

However, you can get a the same effect you want by using an additional rule instead:

```yaml
  rules:    
    - if: $Environment != "sbx"
      when: never
    - !reference [".rules:default", rules]
```

Comment: this will schedule a job when $Environment is `sbx` and will NOT evaluate referenced rules. The job should only get scheduled when environment is `sbx` and when referenced rules are evaluated to `true`

Comment: @LP13 hmm. I don't think that statement is quite correct. The behavior is as follows... if `$Environment` is NOT `sbx`: the job will not run and subsequent rules are not evaluated. If `$Environment` is SBX, the first rule won't match, allowing the subsequent rule to be evaluated. Because the first rule is written in the negative form (`!=`) and uses `when: never`,  this means that all subsequent rules can only be evaluated when `$Environment == "sbx"`. That is to say, this condition is implied for all subsequent rules; the job can only when `$Environment == "sbx"` AND the second rule is true.